# How to invoke AuthorizationFilterAttribute while unit testing in ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I am testing my asp.net web api controller using Visual Studio Test project.

This is how my test case looks:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var controller = new MyController();
    //using json string for providing input
    var input = "{some json object here}"

    var options = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(input);

    var response = controller.GetEmployee(options);

}
```

The above code is working fine.

I have a AuthorizationFilterAttribute.

```
public class UserIdFilterAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext filterContext)
    {
          //Logic to inject a userId to Controller
          ((Controllers.MyController) (filterContext.ControllerContext.Controller)).UserId = userId;
    }
}
```

This `OnAuthorization` function gets called every time when any endpoint (`GetEmployee` in this case) in my controller get invoked. But when I invoke endpoint in the controller using visual studio test framework, `OnAuthorization` function is not getting invoked. I am not using any external mocking framework.

What do i need to do to invoke `OnAuthorization()` automatically when I execute test case?

Comment: If you are unit testing controller then you should not worry about execution of any other code outside of controller. If the changes made to ControllerContext in Authorization attribute are used in the controller code then you should mock or fake the ControllerContext and assign it to Controller and setup it's behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Attribute filters are invoked by the Web API pipeline which is not active during unit tests. You would probably need to do an end to end in-memory integration test to have the framework invoke the action filters.

Other wise set it directly on the controller while testing if it is a publicly available member

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1() {
    var controller = new MyController() {
        //Inject a userId to Controller
        UserId = userId
    };
    //using json string for providing input
    var input = "{some json object here}";

    var options = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(input);

    var response = controller.GetEmployee(options);

}
```

Comment: This actually does solve my issue. I don't know why I did not think of this simple solution. Upvote for that. But the actual question still remains open `when calling any endpoint in my controller via testcase, how can I invoke AuthorizationFilterAttribute`. How can i do end to end testing?

Comment: @OpenStack It will only invoke in integration tests. Attribute filters are cross cutting concerns which can be tested individually. In those cases you have to mock the `HttpActionContext` when exercising the test

Comment: I second @Nkosi, if you want to do a unit test you shouldn't rely on the filter. otherwise it becomes an integration test. But from you comment where you say how do I do end to end testing, suggests you are after some kind of integration testing. In that case you probably want to rely on the [TestHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing) We have built [some tooling around that which you might find helpful](http://geeklearning.io/testavior-a-happy-solution-to-test-your-asp-net-core-applications/)

Answer (score 0):

Tests of your controller should only check for the *presence* of the filter attribute, not the *behavior* of the filter attribute. (That is, absolutely rely on WebAPI's guarantee that it will run all the filters you put on your controllers.)

To test for the presence of the filter:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyControllerTests
{
    [Test]
    public MyController_Has_UserIdFilterAttribute()
    {
        var attribute = typeof(MyController)
                        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(UserIdFilterAttribute))
                        .SingleOrDefault();
        Assert.That(attribute, Is.Not.Null);
    }
}
```

Then, separately, write a test of the filter itself if you like.